# How to change the alarm clock in android?

Tags: android, alarm

Is there a way to pragmatically change the Alarm clock in android ? For example I want to make a program that will change alarm every day 1 minute earlier, so if I set it on friday to ring at 7, in saturday I want to ring in 6 59 and in sunday 6 58 and so on. I know how to make the program but I don't know the part with management of the alarm

Comment: Please release your app for Windows Phone. I have just replaced my Android with one, and I need to get my sleep pattern back in order `;)`

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523350/android-alarm-clock-ui

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about adding this functionality to the stock android alarm app or implementing your own alarm app?

I suggest that you take a look at the source for Clock (*packages/apps/DeskClock/src/com/android/deskclock*) from your android source and understand how the alarm provider / alarm app functions. There is an alarm provider, as the alarms one can set with the system [alarm manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) do not survive a reboot of the device.